# How to group by elasticsearch results/Remove duplicate items from Elasticsearch results

Tags: magento2, attributes, filter, elasticsearch

I need to customize my elasticsearch query based on a custom attribute. I have a product attribute with code `product_code`, I have added this attribute to search and in elasticsearch results, the value for this attributes are populated.

Now, it is possible that some of the products have same product_code value. I need to filter my elasticsearch query to only get a single record for one product_code and discard all later search items having the same code.

I have checked elasticsearch forums and found that it can be done using aggregation. I have tried below code to get unique product_code values, but its not working and I am still getting duplicate product_code records in elasticsearch results.

```
$this->query = [
    'index'            => $this->configProvider->getIndexName($indexIdentifier),
    'body'             => [
        'from'          => $this->getFrom($indexIdentifier),
        'size'          => $this->getLimit($indexIdentifier),
        'stored_fields' => [
            '_id',
            '_score',
            '_source',
        ],
        'sort'          => [
            [
                '_score' => [
                    'order' => 'desc',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'query'         => [
            'bool' => [
                'minimum_should_match' => 0,
            ],
        ],
        /* Code added to find unique product_code values */
        'aggs' => [
            'product_code' => [
                'terms' => [
                    'field'  => 'product_code',
                ],
                'aggs' => [
                    'product_code_docs' => [
                        'top_hits' => [
                            'size' => 1
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'track_total_hits' => true,
];
```